# OWASP ZAP reported “alert(1);” XSS vulnerability, but no popup showed up

Tags: javascript, xss, owasp, zap

OWASP ZAP reported “alert(1);” XSS vulnerability, but we could not get pop up in browser. Is this just a false positive?

The HTML surrounding the injected attack is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  DataSet.FilterBuilder.QueryValuesDictionary['57_ctl00'] = ;alert(1);;
</script>
```

Comment: `Intelex.DataSet.FilterBuilder.QueryValuesDictionary['57_ctl00'] = ;` --- this is not a valid JS code.

Comment: You're definitely vulnerable: the automated tool's simple template might not work in this case, but any real attacker could easily fix it. Also, you should generally include a question statement in your "question".

Comment: Show us the code that generates this html and we'll give you a working xss example.

Comment: ";alert(1);" was passed to the post parameters, otherwise, the code should be: DataSet.FilterBuilder.QueryValuesDictionary['57_ctl00'] = {"__type":"ExpressionPredicate","predicates":[],"expression":null};

Comment: disable pop up blocker

Comment: This is not a false positive. Put `0;alert(1);` (note the added zero) as the post parameter and it will work. But the fact that any input could cause a syntax error in your code is a clear enough sign that it's vulnerable.

Comment: As Jeremy has said, this is a real vulnerability. ZAP has detected that it was able to inject javascript in a way that it can be executed - the fact that this particular attack vector didnt run is immaterial ;) You should always double check the findings of automated tools (as you have done by asking here). You should also try to understand the underlying principles, in this case it looks like an attacker can inject arbitrary javascript into your application - that doesnt sound good does it?

Comment: Even though 0;alert(1) still doesn't work. But I have understood why it is a real vulnerability from Jeremy and Psiinon answers. Thank you!